# I look pretty and I am sweet - What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I look pretty and i am sweet
>
> but still people like to reap me.
>
> I am soft sometimes but still
>
> people use razor knife to cut me
>
> I am here to give you joy
>
> but still people put fire on me
>
> I am here to make you happy
>
> but people use me to smear others face.

So what am I?

Hint 1:

> People can have me at least once a year, but not necessarily.

Comment: Is it a type of food?

Comment: yes....you can eat this

Comment: It is not a banana, is it?

Comment: nope....its not that type of food but it may be a combi pack...:P

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is

> a cake

---

I look pretty and I am sweet
but still people like to reap me.

> We're going to eat it.

I am soft sometimes but still
people use razor knife to cut me

> We use a knife to cut the cake

I am here to give you joy
but still people put fire on me

> We put candles on a birthday cake

I am here to make you happy
but people use me to smear others face.

> Sometimes people smear cake on each other's face, such as a wedding cake or a birthday cake.

Comment: Do people normally smear birthday cakes on other people's faces? I've never actually seen it before, and it sounds kind of weird.

Comment: http://forums.techguy.org/attachments/152686d1246287734/happy_birthday_face_cake.jpg

Comment: I tend to think of the smearing as a wedding-cake tradition.. maybe "cake" is the intended answer and "birthday" and "wedding" are just two possible types of it.  :-)

Comment: @Hellion That does make sense. I'll be busy for a while, I'll edit when I have time.

Comment: @mmking - Yes...  I worked in India for a while, and my teams always made a big fuss over birthday celebrations, and smearing cake on their face was a mandatory part of it.

Comment: How do you like your cake? Smeared not Eaten...